# Cannot access the file because it is being used by another process in VS

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, bundle, appxmanifest

I am creating an appxUpload file for my UWP project release.

When I start creating an appxUpload file, I get following error:

> Error: Cannot open 'C:\Project\Dekstop\obj\Release\Desktop.exe' for
> writing -- 'The process cannot access the file
> 'C:\Project\Dekstop\obj\Release\Desktop.exe' because it is being used
> by another process.' Packager.

This file is not opened in any of the window still it gives me this error.

I emptied the obj folder from all projects and tried rebuilding solution.

Please let me know how I can proceed to get the bundle file of my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be your file is Either Open in another window . Make sure you close the respective file before using it .Use the Task manager to check the Same if some process is using the file . Hope this is Useful.

Comment: We had checked this and all files were closed. This happening only when we are creating the bundle file. On build of the project, the project builds without errors..

Comment: Have you tried re-open Visual Studio and create again.

Comment: Yes. I have tried it. This is an error I am getting for the past two days